# Бессмыслица — способ образования

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

Вопрос из теста

В каком ряду не все слова образованы одинаковым способом?

1. Загривок, пограничный, обветрить, вкруговую.
2. Вслушаться, размечтаться, отыграться, отдышаться.
3. Путаница, бегун, береговой, поздно.
4. **Бессмыслица**, современный, названивать, врассыпную.

В ответах 2-й вариант.

Меня интересует слово **бессмыслица.**
В интернете пишут, что здесь приставочно-суффиксальный способ образования.
Но существительные с суффиксом *иц* образуются от прилагательных:
багряный — багряница;
разный — разница;
ветреный — ветреница.

Если верить интернет-источникам, получается, что это слово образовалось от существительного **смысл.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Меня интересует слово **бессмыслица**. В интернете пишут, что здесь
> приставочно-суффиксальный способ образования.

Можно это слово образовать от слова ***смысл*** приставочно-суффиксальным способом:

*смысл* —> ***бес***-*смысл*-***иц***-*а*.

Но можно образовать его и от слова ***бессмысленный*** — суффиксальным способом, как это делает Тихонов в своём «Словообразовательном словаре русского языка»:

*бессмысл-енн(ый)* —> *бессмысл*-***иц***-*а*.

**Из словаря Тихонова**:

> *мысль* —> *мысл-и-ть* —> *с-мыслить* —>
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

О возможности обоих способов образования этого слова говорится и в «Толковом словаре словообразовательных единиц русского языка» Ефремовой.

Comment: А онлайн словарь Ефремовой есть?В интернете есть Толковый словарь словообразовательных единиц русского языка» Ефремовой. Но там только толкование.

Comment: Серж, Вы, наверное, говорили про этот словарь в интернете:

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/136225 ?

Ну так в нём практически то же, что и в словаре, на который я сослался (у меня бумажный, в интернете я его не видел):

**-иц-(а) <…> VI суффикс

Словообразовательная единица, образующая имена существительные женского рода, которые обозначают неудовлетворительное состояние или недостаток в чём-либо, что названо словами или словосочетаниями со стержневым именем прилагательным**, от которых соответствующие имена существительные образованы (_безвку́сица, безво́дица… и т. п._).

Comment: Да, этот словарь.Но там, как вы видите, нет той статьи, которую вы привели в скриншоте.

Answer (score 2):

Да, это приставочно-суффиксальный способ образования.  Слово образовалось от существительного "смысл".

**БЕССМЫСЛИЦА**, -ы; ж. Разг. То, что не имеет **смысла;** нелепость, вздор. Сказать, услышать бессмыслицу.

В словаре Ефремовой указан этот способ образования: ***БЕЗ — ИЦ***.

И приведены примеры: ***бессмыслица, безвкусица, безработица.***

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**

В словаре Тихонова (издание 1977 года) **нет слова "бессмыслица".** А почему? Здесь можно вспомнить, что Тихонов в более поздних изданиях использовал структурно-семантический анализ для ряда слов.

Возможно, слово "бессмыслица"  было в более ранних изданиях. Можно предположить, что это связано со стилем речи. Есть слово ***бессмысленность***, оно относится к семейству слова "мысль". А для слова "бессмыслица" (разг.) существует **особая статья** в толковом словаре.

Тогда оно вообще может считаться **непроизводным** при формально-семантическом разборе. Однако на практике обычно используется **формально-структурный** морфемный разбор, где выделяется корень ***МЫСЛ***-.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему не от бессмысленный?

Comment: Можно сравнить:  (1) смысл -бессмыслица) и (2) смысл - бессмысленный - бессмысленный. Первый вариант более предпочтительный. Да в словаре дается определение по сущ. смысл.

Comment: Т.е. параллельное словообразование?

Comment: @Серж От "бессмысленный" было бы "бессмысленница".

Comment: В словаре для суффикса ИЦ дается несколько статей с подробной информацией, там все надо учитывать.  Но выбор автором сделан в пользу первого варианта. Надо же еще учитывать влияние приставки БЕЗ, таких примеров нет: бессмысленный - бессмысленница.  Ну и типовая модель БЕЗ...ИЦ для ряда слов.

Comment: безделица, безголосица еще подходят.

Comment: БЕЗДЕЛИЦА, -ы; ж. Разг. То, что незначительно, несущественно, несерьёзно (о факте, обстоятельстве, деле и т.п.); мелочь, пустяк. // =Безделушка.  Может, это уже непроизводное слово, надо у Тихонова смотреть. БЕЗГОЛОСИЦА, -ы; ж. =Безголосье.  Это, наверное, подходит. Ни шагу без словаря))  Это же тест.

Comment: а еще есть мокрица, погодица(название деревни), лужица, рожица, кожица. Кожица - подобие кожи, бессмыслица - без подобия мысли.

Comment: БЕЗДЕЛИЦА БЕЗДЕЛИЦА, -ы, жен. (разг.). 1. Нечто, не имеющее значения, пустяк (в 1 знач.) Ожегов. -ИЦ- имеющее значение, подобие чего-то. То есть лужица - это лужа в которой не промокнешь, она вроде есть, но условно, одно название, а не лужа.

Comment: Суффикс ИЦ многозначный, он может обозначать новое слово, а может служить для субъективной оценки уже существующего слова. Кожица  – ум.-ласкат. слово, а есть, наверное, спец термин.

Comment: @Sharon это ошибочное суждение, мне теперь кажется, но возможно, как вторичный эффект это сравнительное умаление значимости понятия. Уменьшительно-ласкательным называют все без разбора. Уменьшительно-ласкательность - это следствие, а не причина. Причина в частичное  соответствие образу ожидания от.

Comment: иц - это частица чего-то. Относящееся к какому-то понятию или свойству, но в виде частицы не обладающее полнотой признака. Крупица - частица какого-то куска, осколок. Пуговица - от собирать в пук, пучок, собранное, то частица которая собирает.  Царица - жена царя, то есть часть царя, единица - минимальная часть чего-то наборного, половица - часть пола, и тп. Бессмыслица - без единой мысли, без частицы мысли, без частицы образа мысли.

Comment: Класс!  Мне нравится, вы рассуждаете как поэт.  Я бы на вашем месте написала бы книгу об этом. А у меня ведь не суждения, а принятая терминология: суффиксы делятся на словообразовательные и  суффиксы субъективной оценки  https://studfile.net/preview/1621458/page:36/

Answer (score 1):

**Дополнение к первому ответу (информация о словарях)**

1. **Вот словарь**, с которым я работаю https://search.rsl.ru/ru/record/01002823881 Ефремова, Татьяна Фёдоровна.
   **Толковый словарь словообразовательных единиц русского языка** : Ок. 1900 словообразоват. единиц / Т. Ф. Ефремова. - 2-е изд., испр. У меня первое издание (**1996 года).**
2. И вопрос к вам. В тестах допускается такой ответ: ***можно так, а можно по-другому.***
3. **В Интернете** (во многих учебных материалах) предлагается  **приставочно-суффиксальный** способ образования.
   [https://1596.slovaronline.com/41146-бессмыслица](https://1596.slovaronline.com/41146-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)

Теперь будут предлагаться **два способа** (по лучшему ответу на нашем форуме).

4. А вот по поводу словаря **Тихонова** есть вопросы (надо всегда указывать год издания и название).  В издании **1977 года** для слова "мысль" приведена цепочка: ***мысль — мыслить — смыслить — смысл — бессмысленный — бессмысленность.*** Но это все... Может, в других изданиях есть "бессмыслица"?
5. Вы считаете это **правильным**: *смысл — бессмысленный —бессмыслица* вместо *смысл — бессмыслица*? В словаре Ефремовой указаны **не суффиксы**, а словообразовательные **форманты** (БЕЗ...ИЦ  и ИЦ). И вот в моем издании Ефремовой для слова "бессмыслица" указан формант  ***БЕЗ...ИЦ.***

[image: СФормант БЕЗ...ИЦ]

Comment: «_А вот по поводу словаря Тихонова есть вопросы (надо всегда указывать год издания и **название**). В издании 1977 года для слова "мысль" приведена цепочка…_» ===  Sharon, к сожалению, название-то словаря Тихонова, которым пользуетесь, Вы и забыли указать. Но из строения словарных статей я понял, что у Вас не «Словообразовательный словарь русского языка» (он был выпущен в двух томах в 1985 (?) году, переиздан в 1990 году, переиздавался и потом), а  «**Школьный** словообразовательный словарь…», имеющий значительно меньший объём, чем основной словарь Тихонова. Отсюда у Вас и всё непонятки…

Comment: Не похоже, а точно. У меня Школьный словообразовательный словарь, однотомник, издательство  "Просвещение", Москва, 1978 год. Он такой "драный", что я не сразу  год  издания нашла, хорошо, что не выбросила.  Прочитала сейчас историю создания.  Похоже, что это первое издание словаря  гнездовым способом. Составление началось в 1963 году, в 1972 году обсуждалась статья «Проблема создания гнездовых словарей».  Слова «бессмыслица» там нет. Есть еще новое издание 2022 года (гнездовой способ), там вообще ничего нет.

Comment: Полистала обзор  книг Тихонова, там моей нет. А у вас какой год, какое издание и сколько томов (это чтобы «непоняток» ни у кого не было).    https://www.livelib.ru/author/9506/series/listview/biglist/~3

Comment: У меня – второе издание (1990 г.) двухтомного «Словообразовательного словаря» Тихонова. Фото, что поместил в своём ответе, сделал с него. В рассматриваемом нами фрагменте второе издание словаря ничем не отличается от третьего издания 2003 года (я проверял).

Comment: Да, спасибо, первое издание этого словаря 1985 года.  Но в толковом словаре БЕССМЫСЛИЦА, -ы; ж. Разг. То, что не имеет смысла; нелепость, вздор.  Новый смысловой оттенок значения, а не просто нечто бессмысленное. Его вполне могли удалить из гнезда. Кроме того, получается бессмысленный – бессмысленница.  Надо усекать основу на ЕНН, какой-то нелогичный способ образования слова. В Википедии говорится о разных методах разбора у Ефремовой и Тихонова.

Comment: Ну, может, в каких-то других случаях они и разные. Но не в этом. В статье БЕЗ…-ИЦ- Ефремова говорит об образовании с помощью этого форманта существительных **от существительных** и приводит примеры: **безвкусица, безголосица, безработица…** В статье -ИЦ- Ефремова говорит об образовании с помощью этого форманта существительных **от прилагательных** и приводит примеры: **безвкусица, безголосица, безработица…** Как минимум в части возможности образования подобных этим слов от прилагательных с усечением основы последних Ефремова и Тихонов едины.