# В чем смысловое отличие слов: бессмысленность, бессмыслие, бессмыслица?

Tags: лексика, семантика, суффиксы

Чем отличаются эти слова  **по смыслу** и области применения? Можно ли их значение связать со значением разных **суффиксов?**

Собственная словарная статья в толковом словаре Кузнецова есть только для слова **«бессмыслица».**

**БЕССМЫСЛИЦА**, -ы; ж. Разг. То, что не имеет смысла; нелепость, вздор. Сказать, услышать бессмыслицу.

**Примечание**

На форуме осуждалась тема о способе образования слова **«бессмыслица»**. Было предложено два варианта: от прилагательного «бессмысленный» (Тихонов) и от существительного «смысл» (Ефремова).

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475221/Бессмыслица-способ-образования](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475221/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: бессмысленность - что-то не имеющее смысла, не связанное с чем-либо, бесцельность, проживание без цели или действие без намерения, умысла. бессмыслие - че-то старое, неразумение, непонимание - "Старый башкирец молчал и глядел на коменданта с видом совершенного бессмыслия. Пушкин" - то есть по современному башкирец не в теме, не врубается в происходящее. бессмыслица чаще оценка содержания нарратива, отличается эмоциональным окрасом, потому вздор, бессмыслица - это то, что не вяжется с принятой версией происходящего.

Comment: Спасибо, а можно это написать в поле ответа? И еще про суффиксы и про область применения (с примерами))  Просто хочется оформить материал так, чтобы все читали)  Мне нико не хочет почему-то отвечать:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все слова производные слова смысл, произошедшего от корня мысл или мысел.

Связно с греч. μύθος(mythos) - миф.

Мысел арх. догадка, сметка, ум, смысл, толк, рассудок. Даль.

Я бы оставил ум, толк, суждение. Можно добавить идея. Хотя идея - это скорее сверхмысль.

**С+мысл** - с мыслью, **связь с** *какой-то* **идеей**, целью. Мысль связанная.

**Без+смыслие** - отсутствие понимания, связанное, с, скажем, незнанием языка, или каких-то основных понятий. Безсмыслие - это не глупость, а скорее отсутствие разумения в чем-то.

> Старый башкирец молчал и глядел на коменданта с видом совершенного бессмыслия. Пушкин.

Суффикс **ИЦ** - частица, содержащее меру чего-то, частичное соответствие/частично относящееся к. Например, кожа-кожица, рожа - рожица, подобие рожи, частица кожи; вода - водица, водица - какая-то мера воды или что-то обладающее свойством воды, не во всей полноте - "..даром что водица в канавах заморожена.", "Это у тебя дождевая водица...", "водица-то холодненькая, освежит немножко..."; лиственница - название хвойного дерева с мягкими иголками на подобие мелких листьев; ключница - футляр для ключей; грибница - мицелий, сеть корешков относящихся к грибу-плоду; половица - частица пола; метелица - легкая метель, героиня сказки персонификация метели и тд.

**Бес+смысл+иц+а** - без частицы смысла. Чепуха, чушь, вздор, нелепица. Слово имеет эмоционально шутливый или пренебрежительный оттенок.

Суффикс **ОСТ** - суффикс состояния/характеристики, либо понятие состояния. Рад+ость - состояние того кто рад, предсказуемость - что-то предсказуемое, характеристика предсказуемого. Не все слова с **ост** имеют позитивную форму состояния - неизбежность, то чего нельзя избежать, а слова избежность - нет.

**Бес+смысл+енн+ость** - состояние кого-то или чего-то без содержания признака смысла.

**ЕНН** - суффикс причастия или прилагательного, признака процесса, например, мышления.

Хотя бессмысленности можно составить противоположность - осмысленный-осмысленность, но с другой приставкой. Слова смысленность нет, зато есть слово смышление.

> «Буди имя господа бога благословенно от века и до века, яко премудрость и смышление и крепость того есть. Той бо пременяет времена и лета, поставляет царя и преставляет».

**Смышление** - что-то между внимание и понимание. Когнитивные возможности, как сказали бы сейчас.

> ..доходя по всевозможности моих сил и моего смышления, а сообразуяся, впоследствии врачебной науки моей.. Д. С. Самойлович

Наука - это теоретические знания.

И еще добавлю слово **безмыслие** - неспособность вопринимать понятия, представления о чем-то, идеи.

> Я убежден, напротив, что он вовсе ничего не думает, что он решительно не в силах составить понятие, до дикости неразвит, и если чего захочет, то утробно, а не сознательно; просто полное свинство, и вовсе тут нет ничего либерального. И при этом ни одного гамлетовского вопроса: Но страх, что будет там... И в этом ужасно много странного. Неужели это безмыслие в русской природе? Я говорю безмыслие, а не бессмыслие. Ну, не верь, но хоть помысли. В нашем самоубийце даже и тени подозрения не бывает о том, что он называется я и есть существо бессмертное. Он даже как будто никогда не слыхал о том ровно ничего. Достоевский.

Видимо, ответ Пелевина Достоевскому):

> — Началось, конечно, с зависаний в хамлете. Мы все этим грешим, но я зависал в нем не просто на несколько часов. Я мог провести там несколько недель, месяц… Странное безмыслие, где полностью исчезают время, тело и ощущение себя, было самым отрадным в моей жизни. Из-за этого я даже не всегда находил время, чтобы грешить с женщинами. И я задумался — что же происходит в хамлете? Я стал исследовать этот вопрос.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148913/discussion-on-answer-by-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2):

**Заметки по теме:**

Из словаря:

**БЕССМЫ́СЛИЕ,** -я, ср.

1. Отсутствие **смысла, неразумность, нелепость чего-л**. В голосах все еще звучала наивная вера в победу правдивого слова, желание доказать бессмыслие и безумие жестокости. М. Горький, 9-е января.
2. Отсутствие **мысли, мыслительной способности.** Старый башкирец молчал и глядел на коменданта с видом совершенного бессмыслия. Пушкин, Капитанская дочка.

**БЕССМЫ́СЛЕННОСТЬ**, -и, ж. Свойство по знач. прил. бессмысленный. — Если вы, дядюшка, намерены объяснить мне бессмысленность дуэли ---, то я предупреждаю вас — это напрасный труд. И. Гончаров, Обыкновенная история.

**БЕССМЫ́СЛИЦА**, -ы, ж. Разг. Что-л. не имеющее **смысла**; нелепость, вздор. — Это стихотворение совершенная бессмыслица, по-моему, — возразил Неведомов. Писемский, Люди сороковых годов. [Шульгин] не выносил бессмысленных слов. Стоило ему услышать бессмыслицу, как он тотчас приходил в сокрушительную ярость. Паустовский, Далекие годы. || То же, что **бессмыслие (в 1 знач.)**. В этой пьесе есть и протесты, и бунтарство, и драматические раздумья о бессмыслице жизни в современной Америке. Ю. Жуков, Из боя в бой.

Источник (печатная версия): Словарь русского языка: В 4-х т. / РАН, Ин-т лингвистич. исследований; Под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой. — 4-е изд., стер. — М.: Рус. яз.; Полиграфресурсы, 1999; (электронная версия): Фундаментальная электронная библиотека

Вывод: такое впечатление, что через прилагательное **"бессмысленный"** определяется только сущ. "бессмысленность", а это не соответствует словарю Тихонова.